# Django - Can't access data from object in many to many relationship

Tags: python, django, web-deployment

In my Django project, I am trying to create a website that streams TV shows. Each show belongs in many categories, hence the use of many to many relations in my model. What I want to do with a certain page on my website is dynamically load a page of shows belonging to a specific category. However, all of my attempts have ended in failure as I am unable to figure out a way on how to access the actual category data from each show.

**In views.py**

```
def shows_in_category(request, category_slug):
   category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
   showsall = theShow.objects.all()
   shows = []
   for show in showsall:
       print(show.category.name, category.name)
       if show.category.name == category.name:
        shows.append(show)
   print(shows)
   return render(request, 'show/show_list_view.html', {'category':category, 'shows': shows})
```

**In models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)


class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'
    
def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("theshowapp:shows_in_category", args=[self.slug])

class theShow(models.Model):
english_name = models.CharField(max_length=400)

show_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

slug = models.SlugField(max_length=400,unique=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Shows Series'

def __str__(self):
    return self.english_name
```

**In the template (show_list_view.html)**

```
{% for show in shows %}
                    <script> console.log("I'm trying to get in")</script>
                    <script> console.log("{{ show.name }} {{show.category.name}}")</script>
                    <script> console.log("I'm in")</script>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="product__item">
                                
                                <div class="product__item__text">
                                    <ul>
                                    {% for genre in show.category %}
                                        <li>{{ show.category }}</li>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    </ul>
                                    <h5><a href="#">{{ show.english_name }}</a></h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Any insight on this matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where is the `animeShow` model?

Comment: I see that you have some `print` and `console.log` statements. Can you provide the output from these? Some useful statements that can help you debug: `animeShow.objects.all().count()` `animeShow.objects.filter(category__name=category.name).count()`

Comment: @Iain Shelvington The `animeShow` model was actually supposed to be the `theShow` model. I forgot to replace it when I was formatting the code in my question.

@SergioPulgarin From the print statements I had in `view.py`, it out this in the terminal:
`None Action
None Action
[ ]`

Comment: @SergioPulgarin From the print statements I had in `view.py`, it out this in the terminal:
`None Action
None Action
[ ]`, where [] was an empty list. What confuses me the most is how I assigned these objects their categories from django admin and how I'm completely unable to access their values.
From the `console.log` statements, all I received was `I'm entering for loop`, which makes sense because there was an empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read up a bit more on the [many to many fields examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) in Django's documentation and figured out that I should use this:
`shows = animeShow.objects.all().filter(category__name=category)`

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here violates some of the best practices of Django and also isn't using the Django ORM to its full potential. Please replace the lines

```
showsall = animeShow.objects.all()
shows = []
for show in showsall:
    print(show.category.name, category.name)
    if show.category.name == category.name:
        shows.append(show)
print(shows)
```

with

```
shows = animeShow.objects.filter(category__name=category.name)
```

Also in the template change `<li>{{ show.category }}</li>` to `<li>{{ genre }}</li>` since that's the iterating variable.

Comment: I tried out your suggestion and I got a TypeError saying that `'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable`. Could it be that when I return shows that it returns something other than objects?